# Good books for self studying Bayesian

Tags: bayesian

What are some good books with the help of which I can self-study Bayesian from the basics to advanced, mentioning why do we need Bayesian and also which contains numericals, which can boost my concept.

I know the basics of Bayes theorem and conditional, but when it comes to Bayesian my knowledge is very abstract.

So it would be very helpful if I am suggested a good book which I can download online.

Thank You.